# How to calculate growth rate from csv excel data sheet

Tags: python, excel, flask

I am working with a csv sheet which contains data from a brewery, for e.g Data required, Quantity order etc.

I want to write a module to read the csv file structure and load the data into a suitable data structure
in Python. I have to interpret the data by calculating the average growth rate, the ratio of sales for
different beers and use these values to predict sales for a given week or month in the future.

I have no idea where to start. The only line of code I have so far are :

```py
df = pd.read_csv (r'file location')
print (df)
```

Comment: What are you asking? Do you want to know how to structure the application? Have you read any documentation, or some of the thousands of guides and tutorials that are available?

Comment: @AlexanderCécile, I would like to know how I can calculate this growth rate. I have tried the tutorials and guides.

Comment: What sort of growth rate are you looking for? What format is the data in? If it is small enough, Excel might be a better tool.

Comment: @user1558604 I'm looking at growth rate on a month to month basis

Answer (score 0):

To illustrate, I have downloaded data on the US employment level (https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/CE16OV) and population (https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/POP).

```
import pandas as pd

employ = pd.read_csv('/home/brb/bugs/data/CE16OV.csv')
employ = employ.rename(columns={'DATE':'date'})
employ = employ.rename(columns={'CE16OV':'employ'})
employ = employ[employ['date']>='1952-01-01']

pop = pd.read_csv('/home/brb/bugs/data/POP.csv')
pop = pop.rename(columns={'DATE':'date'})
pop = pop.rename(columns={'POP':'pop'})
pop = pop[pop['date']<='2019-10-01']

df = pd.merge(employ,pop)

df['employ_monthly'] = df['employ'].pct_change()
df['employ_yoy'] = df['employ'].pct_change(periods=12)
df['employ_pop'] = df['employ']/df['pop']
df.head()
```